# Need to add one more dropdown with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have managed to populate my drop down menus with a json object, which worked fine.

Html as follows.

```
<form name="contact_form" id="contact_form" >
            <select id="make" name="make">
              <option selected="selected" value="">Make</option>
</select> <br /><br />
            <select name="model"  id="model" disabled="disabled">
              <option selected="selected"  value="">Model</option>
</select> <br /><br />
            <select name="monthly_payment" id="monthly_payment">
              <option selected="selected"  value="">Monthly Payment</option>
              <option value="$299/mo or less">$299/mo or less</option>
              <option  value="$399/mo or less">$399/mo or less</option>
              <option  value="$499/mo or less">$499/mo or less</option>
              <option  value="$599/mo or less">$599/mo or less</option>
              <option  value="$699/mo or less">$699/mo or less</option>
</select> <br /><br />
            <input name="name"  id="name"type="text" value="Name">
            <!--<input name="phone"  id="phone" type="text" value="Phone" maxlength="10">-->
            <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" value="Email">
            <input class="submit-btn" type="button" value=""  id="check_form_button">
          </form>
```

Json, js and jQuery code as follows:

```
    var object    =  {
    "Hyundai":[
        {"Model":"ACCENT","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"AZERA","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"ELANTRA","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"ELANTRA GT","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"GENESIS","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"GENESIS COUPE","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"SANTA FE","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"SANTE FE SPORT","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"SONATA","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"SONATA HYBRID","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"TUSCON","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"VELOSTER","URL":"#"}
    ],
    "Buick":[
        {"Model":"ENCLAVE","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"ENCORE","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"LACROSSE","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"REGAL","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"VERANO","URL":"#"}
    ],
    "GMC":[
        {"Model":"SAVANA CARGO VAN","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"SIERRA 1500","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"SIERRA 2500 HD","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"SIERRA 3500 HD","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"TERRAIN","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"YUKON","URL":"#"},
        {"Model":"YUKON XL","URL":"#"}
    ],
    "Used Car":[
        {"Model":"Used Car","URL":"#"}
    ]
};


function getList(key){
    if(key!=''){
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            var model_html  =   '';
            $.each(object[key], function( index, row ) {

                model_html  +='<option value="'+row.Model+'">'+row.Model+'</option>';
            }); 
            $('#model').removeAttr('disabled').html(model_html);    
        } 
    }else{
            $('#model').attr('disabled',true).html('<option value="" selected="selected">Model</option>');  
        }
}
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
return pattern.test(emailAddress);};

$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("#phone").keydown(function(event) {

    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 


        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 

        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    else {

        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
});
    var html    =   '';
    for (var key in object) {
        html    +='<option value="'+key+'">'+key+'</option>';
    }
    $('#make').append(html);
    $('#make').change(function(){
        getList($(this).val()); 
    });
    $('#name').focusin(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    }).focusout(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='')
            $(this).val('Name')
    });
    $('#phone').focusin(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    }).focusout(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='')
            $(this).val('Phone')
    });
    $('#email').focusin(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    }).focusout(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='')
            $(this).val('Email')
    });
    $('#check_form_button').click(function(){
        var PhoneRegEx = new RegExp("/^[0-9]$/i");

            if($('#make').val()==''){
                alert('Please select a Make');
                return false;
            }
            if($('#model').val()==''){
                alert('Please select a Model');
                return false;
            }
            if($('#monthly_payment').val()==''){
                alert('Please select a monthly payment');
                return false;
            }
            if($('#name').val()=='' ||$('#name').val()=='Name'){
                alert('Please enter Name');
                return false;
            }
            /*if($('#phone').val()=='' || $('#phone').val()=='Phone'){
                alert('Please enter Phone ');
                return false;
            }else if( !$.isNumeric( $('#phone').val() )){
                alert('Phone should be numeric');
                return false;
            }*/
            if($('#email').val()=='' || $('#email').val()=='Email'){
                alert('Please enter  Email');
                return false;
            }else if( !isValidEmailAddress( $('#email').val() )){
                alert('Please enter a valid  Email');
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
                url :   'ajax-php/ajax-send-search-mail.php',
                type :  'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data : $('#contact_form').serialize(),
                success:function(res){
                    $.each(object[$('#make').val()], function( index, row ) {
                    if(row.Model==$('#model').val()) {
                        window.location.href = row.URL; 
                     }
                    });
                }
            });
});
});
```

This code is working fine. Now i wanted to add one more drop down below the "Model" Drop down with label "Trim".

This drop down also need to be disable when page load just like "Model" drop down. 
"Trim" drop down should enable once some value get selected in "Model" drop down.

My question is how can i add the values in "Trim" drop down through json code.

This is the link of jsfiddle for example

http://jsfiddle.net/suresh_p12/QgY6N/2/

Comment: Where is the json value you want to insert in Trim drop down do you want it to add in the same json or it will be fetched at runtime once you select the model value. If you can provide the details we can help better. Anyway i have updated the fiddle without data in trim here is the link - http://jsfiddle.net/visittoravi/QgY6N/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind JSON object "data" to dropdown in following way:

```
    $.each(objdata["TeamList"], function(i, val) {
    $('#ddlteams').append('<option value="' + val.teamid + '">' + val.teamname + '</option>');
});
```

Here lets consider JSON is contain team collection. Change it with your object and its values.